# IIS only serves default document

Tags: .net, iis, iis-7, permissions, http-status-code-403

I've set up a site on my local machine on port 80, and can see the default document at http://localhost/ and http://localhost/default.aspx but when I try to view any other file/directory I get a HTTP Error 401.3 - Unauthorized. I'm using IIS 7 and this isn't one I've ever had before. anonymous authentication is enabled, and I'm not sure what could be causing it.

Comment: What is the URL of another file where you're getting this problem? Is some code getting called which could be assuming authentication?

Comment: Anonymous authentication won't allow you to do directory browsing.  What other files are you trying to access?

Answer (score 0):

You need to allow for Anonymous Authentication by going to your IIS Manager, click on the **Authentication** button on your application's console, Enable Anonymous Authentication and in the opening window select Application Pool identity and click OK. For more details, see this article: http://www.bloggingdeveloper.com/post/HTTP-Error-4013-Unauthorized-Error-While-creating-IIS-70-web-site-on-Windows-Vista.aspx

Comment: Anonymous authentication is enabled.